# Make a Batch File That Keeps Both Files When a Name Conflict Occurs

Tags: batch-file

Is there any way to make a batch file that does not overwrite an existing file when there is a name conflict, but instead keeps both copies of the file in the same path?

Comment: How would you like the duplicate file to be kept?  Change its name?

Comment: @DavidRuhmann , Yes please I want them kept by changing names automatically to avoid name conflicts , thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Batch file below works like COPY command with just one file. If the file already exist in target folder, a number in parentheses is added to new file in order to keep both files.

```
@echo off
Rem mycopy sourceFile targetDir
Set targetName=%~1
Set i=0
:nextName
   If not exist "%~2/%targetName%" goto copy
   Set /A i+=1
   Set targetName=%~1 (%i%)
   Goto nextName
:copy
Copy %1 "%~2/%targetName%"
```