# Batch file to move files based on a list Without overwriting Old file and number of copies

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder with files and a `.txt` file with a list of file names and number of copies that I need to copy from one folder to another.

The script is copying the files but if the `.txt` file has two files of the same name it overwrites the old file.

In the list I have:

> ```
> file1.txt 1
> file2.txt 1
> file1.txt 3
> file2.txt 2
> ```

I want the achieve the following:

> ```
> file1.txt
> file2.txt
> file1(1).txt
> file1(2).txt
> file1(3).txt
> file2(1).txt
> ```

This is the code I have so far:

```
@echo off
set Source=C:\Users\siddique.gaffar\Desktop\Artworks
set Target=C:\Users\siddique.gaffar\Desktop\Artworks Copy
set FileList=C:\Users\siddique.gaffar\Desktop\Artwork TXT File\Book1.txt
echo.

if not exist "%Source%" echo Source folder "%Source%" not found & goto Exit
if not exist "%FileList%" echo File list "%FileList%" not found & goto Exit
if not exist "%Target%" md "%Target%"

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('type "%FileList%"') do copy "%Source%\%%a" "%Target%"


:Exit
echo.
echo press the Space Bar to close this window.
pause > nul
```

Comment: The question is ambigous. Shall the batch avoid overwriting already present files in the target or shall it duplicate the source file if double mentioned in the Filelist?

Comment: What if there is already a file `file1(1).txt` in the target also?

Comment: Related: [Make a Batch File That Keeps Both Files When a Name Conflict Occurs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14033582)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
@echo off 
set Source=C:\Users\siddique.gaffar\Desktop\Artworks
set Target=C:\Users\siddique.gaffar\Desktop\Artworks Copy
set FileList=C:\Users\siddique.gaffar\Desktop\Artwork TXT File\Book1.txt
echo.
if not exist "%Source%" echo Source folder "%Source%" not found & goto Exit 
if not exist "%FileList%" echo File list "%FileList%" not found & goto Exit
if not exist "%Target%" md "%Target%" 

for /F "usebackq tokens=1-2" %%a in ("%FileList%") do call :CopyFile "%%a" %%b


:Exit
echo.
echo press the Space Bar to close this window.
pause > nul
exit /b 0

:CopyFile
:: first argument  = filename
:: second argument = number of copies

REM A little trick that will put limit on 0 if second argument is empty or not a number
set secondarg=%~2
set /a limit=secondarg

REM if limit is invalid (not strict positive), exit the function
IF %limit% LEQ 0 (
    echo Invalid number of copies
    exit /b 1
)
IF NOT EXIST "%Target%\%~1" (
    copy "%Source%\%~1" "%Target%"
    IF %limit% LEQ 1 exit /b 0
    set /a limit-=1
)

REM File already exists: search correct index for filename
set index=0
set "targetfile=%target%\%~n1"
set file_ext=%~x1

:following
set /a index+=1
Rem if file with index %index% already exists, go back to get following index
IF exist "%targetfile%(%index%).%file_ext%" goto :following

Rem we have the correct index, now we can copy
set /a limit=index+limit-1
FOR /L %%g IN (%index%,1,%limit%) DO copy "%Source%\%~1" "%targetfile%(%%g).%file_ext%"
exit /b 0
```

Another option if you have long filenames is the use of `usebackq` and surrounding the path with double quotes in the [`for f`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) loop instead of analyzing the output of the `type` command.

The function `:CopyFile` checks the existence of the file with an `IF EXIST` and uses a counter to find the next index for the filename of the new file. It uses [path manipulation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ben/2007/03/09/path-manipulation-in-a-batch-file/) to construct a new filename with the index.

**EDIT**: I've added the possibility to read the number of copies needed from the textfile and specify that number as second argument to the `:CopyFile` function. If no number is given or the number is not strict positive (greater than 0), it won't make a copy.

PS: the "little trick" I used that will set `%limit%` to 0 in case the second argument is empty works because `set` with the `/a` flag will replace empty variables with 0. This won't work if you use argument variables directly though:

```
set /a limit=%~2
```

will throw an error if the second argument is empty because the cmd parser will substitute `%~2` with an empty string and it will execute `set /a limit=` which is an invalid assignement using the `/a` flag. But if you use an extra variable as transit:

```
set var=%~2
set /a limit=var
```

you'll let `set` handle the variable expansion and not the cmd interpreter. The `set` will see that the `var` variable is empty (in the case `%2` is empty) and will replace it with 0.

Comment: Sorry to let you know I got the following error The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.

press the Space Bar to close this window.

Comment: @sid I forgot to add the source directory in the copy. It should be ok now

Comment: Great to hear that! My pleasure

Comment: @sid can you mark it as solution to your problem if you're satisfied with the answer?

Comment: HI Sorry to bother you, Have been so much help, I have just realised I have not assigned the number of copies wanted e/g in teh text file I have 1 colum with the file1.txt
file2.txt
file1.txt
file2.txt   and in the 2nd column number of copies to be made Either 1 or 2 or 3    Is it possible to adjust the script to allow number of copies to be made ?

Comment: It depends. Can the filename contain spaces?

Comment: Tge filename dose not contain spaces

Comment: Yes it is possible in that case. I'll edit my answer. It would be better if you would edit your original post too though. This way everyone who reads the post will understand the changes in the answer.

Comment: Works Perfect Thank you very much,

Comment: Hi I have another project, want to know if you can help

Comment: @sid Sure. In the following 24hrs I will be AFK though. But after that I'll be glad to help. What can I help you with?

Comment: I need to achieve the following  --     I have a folder with 5,000 images

need a prompt (pop up) to be asked file name wanted and copy from one folder rename file and move copy to a new folder .

Original file name 
Image1.jpg 
Image2.jpg
Rename file 
Image1_1234.jpg 
Image2_1234.jpg
The _1234 will always stay the same 
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Hi Sorry wanted to make sure you got my last message

Comment: You can create a batch-file and use `%n` to get the n-th argument passed to your script or [`set /p var=`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) to ask a user dor input. For the copying part I would recommend the [`copy`](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) command or the more robust [`robocopy`](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

Comment: @sid my apologies for the late answer. This part of the year is a bit busy :-( hope my comment helps. Feel free to ask for help if something is blocking you :-)

Comment: Hi  sorry I am stuck again, I would like the script to search Source sub-folders

Comment: What do you mean with "search Source subfolders"? Maybe you can ask a new question? You'll have the possibility to expand and get helpful answers from other users as well :)

Comment: Sorry I mean search for file in sub-directories of the source folder   EG Source folder is C:\Users\siddique.gaffar\Desktop\Artworks  Within this folder there are sub folders

Comment: Does the target directory have to yield the same directory structure as the target? I.e. if the file is in a subdirectory in the source directory, will it have to be copied in the same subdirectory in the target directory?

Comment: yes it is in a sub-directory in the source      Source=C:\Users\siddique.gaffar\Desktop\Artworks       file are in C:\Users\siddique.gaffar\Desktop\Artworks\LARGE    And C:\Users\siddique.gaffar\Desktop\Artworks\SMALL etc.

Comment: But do you want a SMALL and LARGE directory in your target directory as well?

Comment: Sorry to bother you my new .txt file has also change to  filename filename and number of copies

Comment: small is in a sub directory and large is in another sub directory, and both and in the main directory

Comment: Do you also want a those subdirectories to be created in the target directory?

Comment: Sorry to bother you, I have worked out the issue and now all is working fine

Comment: Great to hear you've been able to find the solution to your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set "Source=C:\Users\siddique.gaffar\Desktop\Artworks"
set "Target=C:\Users\siddique.gaffar\Desktop\Artworks Copy"
set "FileList=C:\Users\siddique.gaffar\Desktop\Artwork TXT File\Book1.txt"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "%FileList%"') do (
if not defined count set "count=1"
cd "%Target%"
if exist %%a (
set "curfile=%%a"
set "curfile=!curfile:~0,-4!"
set "curfile=!curfile!(!count!).txt"
if exist !curfile! (
set /a "count=!count! + 1"
set "curfile=%%a"
set "curfile=!curfile:~0,-4"
set "curfile=!curfile!(!count!).txt"
)
cd "%Source%"
ren "%Source%\%%a" "!curfile!"
xcopy "%Source%\!curfile!" "%Target%"
ren "%source%\!curfile!" "%%a"
) else (
xcopy "%Source%\%%a" "%Target%"
)
)
pause
```

replace all your code by this code. **put this batch file in the same directory wher your files to copy is.** p. s.: for now it works only with .txt files.

Comment: @sid, "it did not work" is not a quite precise error description, is it?

Comment: Sorry did not come up with any error,   THE CMD opened and closed without copying anything,  Maybe I did not put the code in correctly

Comment: I really appreciate all you help, Did not work for me, did not copy any file I did the following   1. saved code to notepad   2. saved file as a .bat  3, click the file to run    Results= no files copies, explore window opens and closes

Comment: Hi  Put the .bat file in the source were the file to be copied are, nothing is been copied, just get a pop up window which opens and closes

Comment: Sorry the same problem, No files are been copied and it opening and closing a window

Comment: Sorry same error, Have doubled checked the paths and all is correct just to make sure have copied and pasted the paths here  SOURCE C:\Users\siddique.gaffar\Desktop\Artworks     TARGET=C:\Users\siddique.gaffar\Desktop\Artworks Copy  FILELIST=C:\Users\siddique.gaffar\Desktop\Artwork TXT File\Book1.txt

Comment: Thank you so much work perfect I will carry out a much larger test at work tomorrow  I appreciate your help

Comment: Sorry I have 1 more issue, If I have 4 file 1 it will only create it twice (file1.txt & file1(1).txt)   can it work so that it copies the same file more than twice

Comment: @HackR_360 the problem is the `goto`. `goto` inside a `for`-loop breaks the loop! Once it has executed the `goto` it will no longer go to the next iteration.

Comment: Hi I got the following error C:\Users\siddique.gaffar\Desktop\Artworks\File1.JPG
1 File(s) copied
C:\Users\siddique.gaffar\Desktop\Artworks\File2.jpg
1 File(s) copied
C:\Users\siddique.gaffar\Desktop\Artworks\File1(1).txt
1 File(s) copied
C:\Users\siddique.gaffar\Desktop\Artworks\File2(1).txt
1 File(s) copied
The system cannot find the file specified.
File not found - (2).txt
0 File(s) copied
The system cannot find the file specified.
File not found - %a
0 File(s) copied

Comment: @sid It's because of the `goto`, it kind of destroys the `for` and its context including the loop variable. That's why it can't recognize it. In [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481558/windows-batch-goto-within-if-block-behaves-very-strangely) it is explained why. In short, a `goto` tells the cmd interpreter: "stop what you were processing and go to the label". It will therefore abandon the `for` and forgot about its context. The same behaviour is encountered with `goto` and labels inside `if` blocks. Follow the link for a more detailed explanation.